# Report a problem with an app I purchased on the Mac App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

I have purchased an app on the Mac App Store which doesn't work at all on my computer. Is there a way to contact the App Store team and report the problem and maybe get a refund?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple will give refunds, though it’s not a very advertised thing.

Point your browser at the [Mac App Store Support Page](http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/), which can also be found in the right side bar of the **Featured** page in `App Store.app`. From there choose `Account & Billing`. From the **Specific Request** select menu, `This app didn't function as expected` should be the option you’re after.

Be polite, state your case, ask nicely (don’t *demand* a refund), and you should have good luck.

Comment: Oh, there it is – thanks! By the way, on my App Store the link is on the *right* side of the "Featured" section.

Comment: @splattne, it’s on the _right_ side for me too, good catch. Original answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using up to now the free download to  'clean up my mac'recently was prompted to purchase it,, which I ve done, but now
I just have a page that says to put the serial number and I havent received anything from apple with a number and Im very confussed
thankyou

Comment: Hi Debbie, welcome to AskDifferent! I'd considering asking this as a new question, which you can do using the 'Ask Question' link in the top right. For now, I'd suggest contacting the developer of the application directly, as anything purchased through the Mac App Store shouldn't require a serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has updated the process to ask for a refund or report a problem. Simply go to https://reportaproblem.apple.com/. Sign-in with your Apple ID and choose the app to report. You can also find the link at the bottom of the iTunes receipt you receive after purchasing an app.

More detailed instructions can be found here: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-get-an-app-refund-from-apple--cms-19757